# jQuery: Set Selected option based on loop variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select that works fine but i'm looking to set the selected value based on a variable in my loop (time_rate_default as below). Since only one time rate default can be true i'd like that to be my selected option.

```
  jQuery.each(time_rates_for_select, function(index, value){
    
    id = value[0]
    rate = value[1]
    name = value[2]
    time_rate_default = value[3] // true or false
    
    $("#time-rate-select").append('<option value="'+ id +'" selected="?">' + rate + ' - ' + name + '</option>');
    
  });
```

How best can I do this? ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a big flow in your code that you assign to undeclared variables:

```
    id = value[0]
    rate = value[1]
    name = value[2]
    time_rate_default = value[3] // true or false
```

At least there're no declarations. So they are assigned to `window`. Use `'use strict';` to make this throw an error.
And please use only `const` or `let` to declare variables. `var` is dangerously outdated.

```
  const $select = $("#time-rate-select");

  $.each(time_rates_for_select, (_, [id, rate, name, time_rate_default]) => {

    $select.append(`<option value="${ id }">${ rate } - ${ name }</option>`);

    time_rate_default && $select.val(id);
    
  });
```

Comment: @DaveC I've updated the code to get use of a JS template literal. Looks more pretty imho. Also we don't use the first `index` argument, so there's a convention to name an unused argument as `_` that makes code less noisy.

Comment: Thank you! This is great code efficiency, also for legibility. :)

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
jQuery.each(time_rates_for_select, function(index, value){

  ....
  time_rate_default = value[3] // true or false
  ....

  var $option = '<option>....</option>'

  if (time_rate_default) {
      $option.attr('selected', 'selected');
  }

  $("#time-rate-select").append($option);

});
```